# glibc 1.22 malloc (ptmalloc2) + Poco (1.5.2) ThreadPool = VERY SLOW ??

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, memory-management, poco

the code uses Poco HTTPServer (+ ThreadPool) to handle REST requests in multiple threads (minThreads=16, max=128).

The box has 12 CPUs, and 'handling the request' means talking to DB or other nodes via network, so the fact #threads > #cpus seems reasonable.

Also, each such request involves JSON processing and is in general pretty malloc-heavy. However, the server is stateless and keeps no caches, so, when server is idling, memory consumption must be quite low.

Now, after prolonged multi-client load (with pauses between tests) I observe the situation when server performance starts to degrade. For example, at the beginning it is ~300 HTTP requests per second with 8 parallel clients. After a day of run it shows 60-80-100 requests per second on the exactly the same requests. No data is changed, requests are readonly.

This condition is permanent until server is restarted, then the performance returns to normal. Memory consumption is reasonable, no memory leaks observed.

After spending lots of time, I managed to figure out the following:

1) single-threaded load doesn't degrade

2) multi-threaded load: degradation happens inside malloc()  - I used Linux 'perf' suite to see that most of time it spends here:

```
<....removed...>
-   39.22%    39.22%         SoLoader
   - _spin_lock
      - 55.86% futex_wake
           do_futex
           compat_sys_futex
           sysenter_dispatch
         - 0xb775f420
            - 87.48% operator new(unsigned int)
               + 27.60% std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&)
               + 11.59% operator new[](unsigned int)
```

This tells me there is a lot of contention on allocations. It is also confirmed by huge context switch rate when server is 'slow' compared to when server is 'fast',

3) playing with MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=1 on 'fast,restarted' server gives almost the same behavior of 'slow' server

This brought me to a conclusion that under my pattern of load, Poco ThreadPool thread creation/retention/deletion policy + glibc malloc thread-to-arena assignment heuristics together cause a degenerate situation when all (or most) Poco worker threads (in a pool) are mapped to the same malloc arena. This mapping happens on 1st malloc made by a thread, and remains for the life time of the thread. When parallel load happens, these workers contend for malloc(). This is fixed by restart, and slowly happens again after prolonged load.

To reiterate: I have 32-bit server process, 12-cpu box, I observe 24 arenas within the server process (matches malloc() documentation for arenas). Arena sizes are very uneven. There are lots of threads in the process, most are idling, and Poco is configured to keep 16 workers at minimum. Tests normally go as 8 parallel clients making short requests to server, but sometimes level of parallelism can be 16 or even higher. After 15-60 seconds of test, there is a pause when server is idle.

The question is: had anyone met such problem before? What are possible solutions for such degradation?

I've tried TCMalloc and it seems to help, but doesn't look like a solution (for non-technical reasons). I wonder that glibc malloc() is so vulnerable to threaded load...

Comment: "I've tried TCMalloc and it seems to help, but doesn't look like a solution" - but that's exactly the right solution.   You want thread local storage for each thread and only rarely lock the main storage area

Comment: glibc malloc (ptmalloc2) DOES provide thread-local storage for each thread - as we can see, at the beginning all threads work fine and scalable. The problem is that as threads come and go (and sometimes exceed number of per-thread arenas), the situation becomes worse, more and more threads are sharing the same arena and contend for malloc

Comment: As you're saying it does *not* provide thread-local storage *for each thread* which is exactly the problem.

Comment: that's true. however under normal load we have # threads < # arenas, which is supposed to be handled well by glibc malloc, but apparently it's not